# android - troubles integration Tess-two library with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I'm tryin' to set up *Tess-Two library* in ***Android Studio*** using this instruction:
[Tess-two instruction for Android Studio](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-184181)

But I fail on the step 8 - it says something like "android" is not the system command (or something like this - my OS is not in English). So how to install *Tess-two* till the end?

Comment: You need to add the "android" executable to your  PATH.

Comment: @rmtheis where can I find "android" executable? and "ant" executable (step 9). And do I need to copy smth else but those EXEs?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=add+android+sdk+to+path